# Problems with async geocoder.geocode

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm having trouble getting the position of an address. However, this problem occurs only the first time that I run, ie it is necessary that every time I make the query, I click twice, for only the second values are obtained.

I believe the problem is due to be asynchronous method. But I am not able to solve the problem. Some of his friends could help me.

```
$('#btnTracar').click(function(){
if (geocoder){
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': document.getElementById('txtStart').value }, function(results, status){
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            mapStart = results[0].geometry.location;
        } else { alert("Não foi possível carregar a localização. \nDescrição do Erro: " + status); }
    });

    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': document.getElementById('txtEnd').value }, function(results, status){
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            mapEnd = results[0].geometry.location;
        } else { alert("Não foi possível carregar a localização. \nDescrição do Erro: " + status); }
    });

    calcularRota();
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
        $('#btnTracar').click(function(){
            if ($.trim($("#txtStart").val()) == ""){
                alert("Favor preencher o campo de Origem Corretamente.");
                return;
            }

            if ($.trim($("#txtEnd").val()) == ""){
                alert("Favor preencher o campo de Origem Corretamente.");
                return;
            }

            if (geocoder){
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': document.getElementById('txtStart').value }, function(results, status){
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
                        mapStart = results[0].geometry.location;
                        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': document.getElementById('txtEnd').value }, function(results, status){
                            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
                                mapEnd = results[0].geometry.location;
                                calcularRota();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```